# how to edit a file in bash script gracefully

Tags: bash

i have a text file which contains some specified strings, firstly locate them , delete few lines between them , then add something new.  .e.g

```
$cat foo.txt
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
####start
123456
987655
121212
####end
cccccc
dddddd


$ cat bar.txt
AA
BB
CC
```

now, i want a bash script to edit foo.txt.  delete content between  "####start" and "####end" , insert content of bar.txt

new foo.txt will be

```
$cat foo.txt
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
####start
AA
BB
CC
####end
cccccc
dddddd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can execute the following command,

```
sed -i '/####start/,/####end/{//!d};/####start/r bar.txt' foo.txt
```

The first part "/####start/,/####end/{//!d}" is to remove the lines in between the pattern and second part "/####start/r bar.txt" is to add the contents of bar.txt to foo.txt.

```
**Test:**

✓ krishna-VB# cat foo.txt 
aaaaa
bbbbbb
####start
123465
454687
146546
####end
cccccc
dddddd

✓ krishna-VB# cat bar.txt 
AA
BB
CC

✓ krishna-VB# sed -i '/####start/,/####end/{//!d};/####start/r bar.txt' foo.txt

✓ krishna-VB# cat foo.txt
aaaaa
bbbbbb
####start
AA
BB
CC
####end
cccccc
dddddd
```

If you want to verify the just output before modification of file, you can remove '-i' option before sed.

Comment: interesting , it is very simple.  i want to learn the usage of  //!  in {//!d} ,  where can i  find the doc

Answer (score 1):

This awk one-liner should help:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;n=NR;next}
    !p;/##start/{p=1;for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print a[i];}/#end/{p=0;print}' bar foo
```